# Math Equation Pattern

Tags: java

I am creating a pattern that, when user enters the number of rows, prints a triangle with a specific number pattern. I am having a hard time coming up with a mathematical equation that will output this pattern:

[image]

I have already written a code that works but not with the pattern that I am wanting to create. Can someone help me?

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trianglePattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {
            System.out.format("%"+4*(rows-i+1)+"s","");
            for(int j=i+1; j>1; j--)
                System.out.format("%4d", j);
            for(int j=1; j<=i+1; j++)
                System.out.format("%4d", j);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It is not Pascal's triangle at all. The numbers are just powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  The spacing is based on several factors.

1. The sum of the field widths. Each field width is kept is a list.  It is used to reduce the leading space based on the row being printed.
2. That each column field width is sized for the maximum value in that column.  The width for a given column is also maintained in a list. Since the widths are symmetric about the central column, left side formats are also used to print right side values.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        List<Integer> fws = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fmts = new ArrayList<>();
        Function<Integer, Integer> fw = r -> (int) (Math
                .log10(1 << r)) + 2;
        int sumWidths = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        int f = fw.apply(r);
        fws.add(f);
        sumWidths += f;
        fmts.add("%" + f + "d");
        }

        rows--;
        String pad = " ".repeat(sumWidths);
        for (int r = rows; r >= 0; r--) {
            System.out.print(pad);
            int v = 1;
            for (int c = r; c < rows; c++) {
                System.out.printf(fmts.get(c), v);
                v <<= 1;
            }
            System.out.printf(fmts.get(rows), v);
            for (int c = rows-1; c >= r; c--) {
                v >>= 1;
                System.out.printf(fmts.get(c), v);
            }
            System.out.println();
            pad = pad.substring(r > 0 ? fws.get(r-1) : pad.length());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice problem...

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
    int rows = input.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    for(int i=rows-2; i>-1; i--) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    // I print this here just for your help(delete it afterwards)
    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.print(((int) Math.pow(2, integer)) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    for(int i=rows; i>=1; i--) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            int number = ((int) Math.pow(2, integer-i+1));
            if(number>=1) {
                System.out.format("%d\t", ((int) Math.pow(2, integer-i+1)));
            } else {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

(Tip): in the Arraylist list i save all the exponents i need to calculate the last row of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Switched the loops, added a power function and fiddled a little with the loop indexes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trianglePattern {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rows?: ");
    int rows = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      System.out.format("%"+4*(rows-i+1)+"s","");
      for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.format("%4d", (int) Math.pow(2,j));
      for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        System.out.format("%4d", (int) Math.pow(2,j));
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```